# background image is stuck in a certain spot within a div

Tags: css, image

I have an background image that is smaller than the div it is located in. I want to set its position with in the div.

I tried

`background:url(../img/logo.png ) transparent no-repeat fixed ; background-position: 75px -200px;`

No matter what i do to position the image it wont move. what could be causing this.

Comment: user edited question to say *"Nevermind I figured out the reason right away. My jquery script was messing with it. thanks anyway."*

Answer (score 0):

Is the DIV a block element with set width and height? If yes this should work:

`background: transparent url(http://placehold.it/100x150) no-repeat 75px -200px;`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have specified the position of background images somewhere else in your code. What does the rest of your css look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using short code for the background properties, include the position also.  You don't need to set it as fixed.  Try this:

```
background:url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat 75px -200px;
```